# Core Data: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

First of all I want to point out that there are many questions that report a similar error, but mine is a different case.

I have these three Core Data entities:

1. Training, that has a collection of FeatureSet objects
2. FeatureSet, that has a collection of FeatureGroup objects
3. FeatureGroup, that has only numeric fields

Every entity has its inverse relationship (e.g. FeatureSet has the inverse many-to-one relationship with Training).

[image]

These three methods of a helper class perform the insertion of the objects into the managed object context:

```
// MARK: - Insertion
func insertFeatureGroup(_ groupDict:[String:Any], inSet set:FeatureSet, forData data:String) -> FeatureGroup? {
    guard let group = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "FeatureGroup", into: self.context) as? FeatureGroup else { return nil }

    group.data = data
    group.set = set
    if let min = groupDict["min"] as? Double { group.min = min as NSNumber }
    if let max = groupDict["max"] as? Double { group.max = max as NSNumber }
    if let mean = groupDict["mean"] as? Double { group.mean = mean as NSNumber }
    if let median = groupDict["median"] as? Double { group.median = median as NSNumber }
    if let deviation = groupDict["deviation"] as? Double { group.deviation = deviation as NSNumber }
    if let skewness = groupDict["skewness"] as? Double { group.skewness = skewness as NSNumber }
    if let kurtosis = groupDict["kurtosis"] as? Double { group.kurtosis = kurtosis as NSNumber }
    return group
}

func insertFeatureSet(_ featuresDict:[String:Any], inTraining training:Training) -> FeatureSet? {
    guard let set = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "FeatureSet", into: self.context) as? FeatureSet else { return nil }
    guard let sequenceNumber = featuresDict["sequenceNumber"] as? Int16 else { return nil }

    training.addToSets(set)
    set.training = training
    set.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber

    if let heartRate = featuresDict["heartRate"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let group = insertFeatureGroup(heartRate, inSet: set, forData: "heartRate") {
            set.addToGroups(group)
        }
    }

    if let rotationRate = featuresDict["rotationRate"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let group = insertFeatureGroup(rotationRate, inSet: set, forData: "rotationRate") {
            set.addToGroups(group)
        }
    }

    if let userAcceleration = featuresDict["userAcceleration"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let group = insertFeatureGroup(userAcceleration, inSet: set, forData: "userAcceleration") {
            set.addToGroups(group)
        }
    }

    if let altitude = featuresDict["altitude"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let group = insertFeatureGroup(altitude, inSet: set, forData: "altitude") {
            set.addToGroups(group)
        }
    }

    if let course = featuresDict["course"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let group = insertFeatureGroup(course, inSet: set, forData: "course") {
            set.addToGroups(group)
        }
    }

    if let speed = featuresDict["speed"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let group = insertFeatureGroup(speed, inSet: set, forData: "speed") {
            set.addToGroups(group)
        }
    }

    return set
}

func insertTraining(activity:String) -> Training? {
    guard let training = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Training", into: self.context) as? Training else { return nil }
    training.activity = activity
    return training
}
```

And this is how I perform the fetch:

```
// MARK: - Fetch
var trainings:[Training]? {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Training", in: self.context)
    request.entity = entity

    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]

    do {
        guard let trainings = try self.context.fetch(request) as? [Training] else {
            return nil
        }
        return trainings
    } catch {
        print("Error Fetching Trainings: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to access the groups property of a featureSet object. Let's support that in some part of my code I fetch all the trainings (and they are fetched successfully):

```
guard let trainings = <myUtilityClassInstance>.trainings else { return }
guard let myTraining = trainings.first else { return }
guard let mySet = myTraining.sets.first as? FeatureSet else { return }
print(mySet.groups)
```

The last line of code produces an exception: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1700994b0". If I try to inspect the class of the object *mySet*, I can see that it's actually a FeatureSet object. This class has a "groups" property. However, it seems like the groups property is not recognised and accessing it produces an exception. 
My Xcode project is big and I realise that the problem may be in other parts of the code. I am looking for a suggestion on how to investigate this exception.

**PS**: I am using the classes (Training, FeatureSet, FeatureGroup) that are generated automatically by Core Data, which include some accessors for the properties (e.g. methods to add/remove a group in a FeatureSet).

**Update**: the *FeatureSet* class definition is empty, but these are the extensions that were automatically generated by CoreData:

```
extension FeatureSet {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<FeatureSet> {
        return NSFetchRequest<FeatureSet>(entityName: "FeatureSet")
    }

    @NSManaged public var sequenceNumber: Int16
    @NSManaged public var groups: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var training: Training?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for groups
extension FeatureSet {

    @objc(addGroupsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToGroups(_ value: FeatureGroup)

    @objc(removeGroupsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromGroups(_ value: FeatureGroup)

    @objc(addGroups:)
    @NSManaged public func addToGroups(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeGroups:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromGroups(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of the FeatureSet class, particularly where groups is defined?

Comment: @clarus I added the code.

Comment: The error would normally say which class and which selector caused the problem.  Do you have that?  (I know you're assuming `FeatureSet.groups` but is that what it actually reports?)

Comment: @PhillipMills "[My_Target.FeatureSet groups]"

Comment: I wonder if it might actually be because of the print() itself. If you put mySet.groups in a variable instead of printing it, does it still crash?

I think that `NSSet?` is going to be treated as `Set<AnyObject>?` in Swift, and that you might have to iterate through the elements to print them, or convert the `NSSet?` to something else in order to print it directly.

Comment: @clarus If I declare a variable and assign it to the groups property of the FeatureSet object, it crashes right in that line. It seems like the groups property is unaccessible for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the *NSManagedObjectContext* object used to fetch the data was deallocated when I was trying to access the *FeatureSet*'s *groups* property. More info on the matter can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html).